# How can I catch a python loop result in one variable

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to loop  my database output and get the result of each loop as variable with following code.

```
for item in output:
    v=''.join(item)
    link="https://example.com/user/{}".format(v)
    print(link)
```

I already tried to put that in a variable with:

```
var=for item in output:
    v=''.join(item)
    link="https://example.com/user/{}".format(v)
    print(link)
```

but that did not work

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but probably you want to initiate an empty list or dictionary before the loop that you can then fill during the loop

Comment: Are you trying to get all the items into one variable, after that create the link and print it ?

Comment: @ionut exactly, that was my goal. The answer below did work for me. Thank's for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might mean that you want a list of links:

```
var = ["https://example.com/user/{}".format(''.join(item)) for item in output]
```

Comment: Pythonic is the way